# Google Drive SDK authorized GET request using downloadUrl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-drive-api, httparty

In my Rails 3 app, I am able to successfully authenticate using Oauth2 and able to get the metadata for a file.  The downloadUrl is

https://doc-10-3o-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/tj647mo7q16s2rquitcrcv800pkn7gcf/ap67p147th03cn8rjpu68i8qva3p7i8j/1345240800000/02289284805103305740/02289284805103305740/0BwsQ03A3DXbCTVBjUDlNNzNJNDQ?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true

The documentation states that I must do the following:

*Gets a file's metadata by ID. To download a file's content, send an authorized HTTP GET request to the file's downloadUrl*

I do not wish to use Google APIs Client Library for Ruby, but simply formulate a HTTP Request using HTTParty

Here is a snippet of the code I've been trying to get to work

```
response = HTTParty.get(https://doc-10-3o-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/tj647mo7q16s2rquitcrcv800pkn7gcf/ap67p147th03cn8rjpu68i8qva3p7i8j/1345240800000/02289284805103305740/0?access_token={token})
open("/User/mymachine/test.pdf", 'wb'){|pdf| pdf << response.body}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm formulating the request wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `Authorization: Bearer` header to your request, together with the access token you retrieved during the OAuth 2.0 flow.

Basically, your HTTP request must look like the one in the OAuth 2.0 documentation:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#callinganapi

I'm not a Ruby expert, but the request using HTTParty should be:

```
response = HTTParty.get(downloadUrl, :headers => {"Authorization" => "OAuth {token}"})
```

Where `downloadUrl` is the one you got from the file's metadata and `token` is the access token you retrieved when performing authorization.

Comment: Getting the same result.  response.message states "Unauthorized"  I know that the access_token is fine because I can add it to other api calls and it works.  I doubled checked the scope and I have the proper rights there as well.

Comment: It would be great if you could capture the HTTP request that is sent by your code so that can take a look at that. Also, try sending the same request using the OAuth 2.0 Playground: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: Thanks for recommending the "oauthplayground" link.  It revealed the I was entering the authentication in incorrectly.  Here is correct syntax response = HTTParty.get(downloadUrl,:headers => {"Authorization" => "OAuth ya29.AHES6ZRSSHTN8cjeqcvAayYsNF25UpdLkTzCB_dmRl9OrxZ_-XXXX"}) I've updated the code.  It was also essential to remove the colon ":" after "OAuth" leave a space and then add the access_token.  Works like a charm now.